# c# Login from other computer

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm busy with making a launcher for a game I'm building. The launcher is just a simple login form so far... I worked on it for a few days and only now it works.

I made it in C# in Visual Studio 2015 and with a SQL Database on local laptop.

When I run the program on my desktop it works, but when I log in it totaly freezes and after a long time there comes an error. It looks like my desktop cannot connect to the database to find the username and password.

This is the code I used to connect and login with the database:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=login5;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from user1 where username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", cn);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count += 1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in!");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe");
        }

        else if (count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect!");
        }

        textBox2.Clear();
    }
```

How do I make it work so I can connect from anywhere to the database?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add the connection string to the application
       configuration file (app.config).
2. You need to put the name of the SQL server correctly. In your code you are connecting to  .\sqlexpress, instead of the dot (.) put the name of the SQL server. dot means localserver, you are connecting to local server, if the application is not running on the SQLServer machine it will not be able to connect.
3. while opening a connection to the database, read the connection string from the database.
4. you should close the connection - there are a lot of articles online to teach you how to make the best practice.

If you fix the above points and you still have problem, please share the exception.

Answer (score 0):

To connect from anywhere to the database
 - Your database should be deployed on a server with **a reachable name or Ip** from anywhere
 - Your authentication mode should be **sql authentication mode**
 - your database **server should be configured to allow remote connection**

your connection string will look like this one `@"Server=myServerNameOrIp\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"`

Comment: Allright, thanks!

- I have a reachable IP
- I want to set an account on "SQL server configuration manager" on my server but there is the problem. Give a account name and password but it gives an error: "The given networkpassword was incorrect [0x80070056]"

I tried to find the password but I can't find it.. any help here?

- Remote connection should be up and running now.

Please help me with the password!